# Laravel Google Maps

Tags: laravel, google-maps

Muy buenas tardes para todos!!!

Les comento, estoy tratando de implementar un buscador de google maps en el header de una página hecha en laravel...  con mi script actual logro hacerlo funcionar a la perfección SOLAMENTE dentro del content pero no en el menu de la cabecera de la página...

por ejemplo si creo "search.blade.php"

```
@extends('land.layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address_address">Address</label>
        <input type="text" id="address-input" name="address_address" class="form-control map-input">
        <input type="text" name="address_latitude" id="address-latitude" value="0" />
        <input type="text" name="address_longitude" id="address-longitude" value="0" />
    </div>
    <div id="address-map-container" style="width:100%;height:400px; ">
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%" id="address-map"></div>
    </div>
    
    @section('scripts')
        @parent
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{ env('GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY') }}&libraries=places&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
        <script src="/js/mapInput.js"></script>
    @stop

@endsection
```

y agrego el @yield('scripts') en app.blade.php esto funciona perfecto y al buscar una direccion aparece la latitud y la logntud en los campos sin problema si ingreso en domain.com/search

Bien pero ahora necesitaría poner este buscador en la cabecera en el menu.

probe con un @yield('search') y @section('search') en el index.blade.php...

probe haciendo un @include('land.search')

En ambos casos, muestra el buscador, los 2 campos de latitud y longitud... y cuando busco una dirección la muestra correctamente en el mapa sin más, pero no me pone las coordenadas en el campo de latitud y longitud  alguien podría decirme que está mal?

edito: agrego el archivo .js

```
function initialize() {

    $('form').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (keyCode === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
    const locationInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("map-input");

    const autocompletes = [];
    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    for (let i = 0; i < locationInputs.length; i++) {

        const input = locationInputs[i];
        const fieldKey = input.id.replace("-input", "");
        const isEdit = document.getElementById(fieldKey + "-latitude").value != '' && document.getElementById(fieldKey + "-longitude").value != '';

        const latitude = parseFloat(document.getElementById(fieldKey + "-latitude").value) || -33.8688;
        const longitude = parseFloat(document.getElementById(fieldKey + "-longitude").value) || 151.2195;

        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(fieldKey + '-map'), {
            center: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
            zoom: 13
        });
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
        });

        marker.setVisible(isEdit);

        const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.key = fieldKey;
        autocompletes.push({input: input, map: map, marker: marker, autocomplete: autocomplete});
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < autocompletes.length; i++) {
        const input = autocompletes[i].input;
        const autocomplete = autocompletes[i].autocomplete;
        const map = autocompletes[i].map;
        const marker = autocompletes[i].marker;

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            marker.setVisible(false);
            const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

            geocoder.geocode({'placeId': place.place_id}, function (results, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    const lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    const lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    setLocationCoordinates(autocomplete.key, lat, lng);
                }
            });

            if (!place.geometry) {
                window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
                input.value = "";
                return;
            }

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(17);
            }
            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            marker.setVisible(true);

        });
    }
}

function setLocationCoordinates(key, lat, lng) {
    const latitudeField = document.getElementById(key + "-" + "latitude");
    const longitudeField = document.getElementById(key + "-" + "longitude");
    latitudeField.value = lat;
    longitudeField.value = lng;
}
```

Comment: bueno, de primera lo que está mal es que no pones el contenido de `mapInput.js`

Comment: hola! agregado, mala mía, no lo puse porque como en content funciona todo bien pense que el error estaba en como estaba llamando a los blades!

Comment: me parece confuso que declares un mapa por cada input con clase `map-input`. Incluso si tuvieses varios campos de texto es mala idea instanciar dos mapas salvo para casos de uso muy específicos.  Yo partiría, de todos modos, logueando la ocurrencia de `place_changed`. Si el marker se dibuja entonces estás entrando ahí.  Por otro lado... para qué llamas al geocoder? el eventos `place_changed`ya tiene coordenadas

Comment: para lo que necesito mas adelante me va bien, como decia esto esta funcional.. el problema es cuando intento ponerlo en otro blade y llamarlo al app.blade.php